# How to call function within a function

Tags: javascript

I tried many things already, nothing works. How do I mock the promise return `await this.getDbClient().put(params).promise();`

Any help?

```
 const car: Car = {
    id: 892421
};    



it('#DatabaseHandler should create car', async () => {
        DatabaseHandler.getDbClient().put = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => car); 
        const result = await DatabaseHandler.createCar(car); // error here
        expect(result).toEqual(car);
    });
```

DatabaseHandler

```
import { DynamoDB } from 'aws-sdk';
import { DocumentClient } from 'aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb';
import { Car } from '/opt/nodejs/models/car.interface';

const documentClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

export class DatabaseHandler {
    private static tableName: string = 'cars';

    static getDbClient = (): DynamoDB.DocumentClient => {
        return documentClient;
    }

    static createCar = async (car: Car) => {
        const params: DocumentClient.PutItemInput = {
            TableName: this.tableName,
            Item: car
        }
        await this.getDbClient().put(params).promise();
    }
}
```

> TypeError: this.getDbClient(...).put(...).promise is not a
> functionJest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `put` method returns an object that has a `promise` method you are not mocking that one.

Try this

```js
DatabaseHandler.getDbClient().put = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  // returning an object that has the promise method
  return {
    promise: () => Promise.resolve(car)
  }
});
```